# Is it possible to use a custom android widget written in Java whilst using MonoDroid?

Tags: java, android, widget, xamarin.android, port

Errmm yeah, I was hoping to use the [RangeSeekBar](http://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) in my MonoDroid application - but honestly, I'm not even sure if this is possible / what the best option is / where to even start?

Do I need to port the entire code? Write some sort of wrapper?

Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the RangeSeekBar is available as part of a bound JAR library you could bind it to your project using [JAR-binding](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29) . Which is probably the easiest way.

If a bound JAR-library isn't available you can use the [Java Native Interface](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Working_With_JNI). But this solution is a lot more complicated.